# why can't I use .split()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, arguments

I'm certain I don't have a grasp on what kind of variable is being passed. I was under the impression that when I call the function permutation('abc'), I'm passing a string into the function. But then when I try to use the method .split it gives me an error .split is not a function. So I solved it by using Array.prototype.slice.call(str), but the question still remain why .split is not an option. My code is as follows:

```
function permutation(str, n) {
  array = Array.prototype.slice.call(str); // why not array = str.split('');
  n = n || array.length;

  if (n == 1) {
    console.log(array.join(''));
    return array.join('');
  } else {
    for (var i=0; i<n;i++) {
      permutation(array, n-1);
      if (n%2 == 0) {
        swap(array,i,n-1);
      } 
      else {
        swap(array,0,n-1);
      }
    }
  }
}

function swap(array, i, j) {
  temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;
  return array;
}

permutation('abc');
```

Comment: Because this line inside: `permutation(array,n-1)`, your recursive call is passing what is now an array. The very first call to permutation is a string, all recursive calls are going to be passing an array because of it.

Comment: `permutation(array,n-1)` does not appear to pass a string…

Comment: It is on the 2nd iteration that it is erroring. The first iteration, `str` is a string, but then in subsequent calls, you pass an array with `permutation(array, n-1)` You will want to pass `array.join('')` instead and it should work.

Comment: Although, I am not entirely sure why you are converting to an array in the first place? Indexed access and character swapping can all be done as strings.

Comment: @mhodges if you throw in an array of numbers with slice it will give you the correct permutations. With split it will error.

Comment: @Matt My point was that the OP should never have to split into an array. You can keep the value as a string and check length, do character indexing/swapping. Converting back and forth between strings and arrays is an unnecessary complexity that is the root cause of the OP's issues.

Comment: mhodges thanks a lot! I can't believe I didn't see that :p I was so obsessed with the first iteration I didn't even think about future iterations. @matt thanks a lot for the alternative solution I will definitely give it a try solving the problem as you mentioned. The one follow up question would be what are OP's issues?

Comment: @manuel "OP's issues" was referring to the issues you were having as a result of switching back and forth between strings and arrays. A prototype method for `slice()` exists on both `String` and `Array`, however the same is not true for `split()`. This explains the inconsistent behavior

Comment: @manuel, OP is Original Poster, in this case you. They were just referring to your issues without having to refer to you by name.